# How can I know if any cell phones other than a given set are turned on in the nearby area?

Tags: sniffer, identity, gsm, signal-analysis, 3g

I am searching for a solution to identify phones simply by the signals it emits.
Imagine a signal receiver in a room, then I want to know which people are using phones nearby. I don't care what they are used for, just the fact that they are turned on.

I can't really use Wifi or Bluetooth for this since it can be turned off.
3G/GSM etc. can also be turned off, but I would like to hear if it is possible to "sniff" these signals and identity them.
I have to identify the signals since there are a specific group of people whose phones are "allowed" to be turned on. Then I want to know if anyone else than those people have their phone turned on nearby.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.netlinetech.com/ They create some RF detection equipment you would need to do such scanning, but this only works if the device is communicating with a tower in some way shape or form. Is this for personal reasons? If this is for a business there are systems from them available to provide access control of cell devices through the means of a virtual base station set up on site. You can block or whitelist specific phones or entire services/bands.